# how to get count of records from 2 tables based on value in a particular column from 1st table using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count

These are the tables I am fetching count from

register

```
+----+-------------+--------+
| id | empSignupId | cityId |
+----+-------------+--------+
| 42 |           4 |      1 |
| 47 |           3 |      1 |
| 48 |          11 |      1 |
| 54 |          20 |      1 |
| 55 |          21 |      2 |
| 56 |          22 |      2 |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

guest_list

```
+-----+------------+-------------+
| id  | guestName  | empSignupId |
+-----+------------+-------------+
| 103 | Mallica SS |           3 |
| 104 | Kavya      |           3 |
| 108 | Vinay BR   |          11 |
| 109 |  Akash MS  |          11 |
+-----+------------+-------------+
```

cities

```
+----+---------------+
| id | cityName      |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | Bengaluru     |
|  2 | Chennai       |
|  3 | Sydney        |
|  4 | New York City |
|  5 | Shanghai      |
|  6 | Chicago       |
+----+---------------+
```

I need to fetch the count of people registered from particular city which includes people, their guests, if guests are not present also it should show the count of people.

This is what I tried

```
SELECT COUNT(gl.id) +  COUNT(rfs.id), ct.cityName, rfs.cityId  
FROM register rfs 
INNER JOIN cities ct ON ct.id=rfs.cityId 
INNER JOIN guest_list gl ON gl.empSignupId = rfs.empSignupId 
GROUP BY rfs.cityId;

+-------------------------------+-----------+--------+
| COUNT(gl.id) +  COUNT(rfs.id) | cityName  | cityId |
+-------------------------------+-----------+--------+
|                             8 | Bengaluru |      1 |
+-------------------------------+-----------+--------+
```

I also need the count of people from other cities to be displayed, since there are no guests from some cities its not returning that count.

Please help me figure this out, I am still new to MySQL.. any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You fist need to aggregate `guest_list` table in order to get the number of records per `empSignupId`:

```
SELECT empSignupId, COUNT(empSignupId) AS countGuest
FROM guest_list gl 
GROUP BY empSignupId
```

**Output:**

```
empSignupId countGuest
----------------------
3           2
11          2
```

Now you have to use a `LEFT JOIN` to the derived table above in order to also get the number of records for each city:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(countGuest), 0) + COUNT(rfs.id), ct.cityName, rfs.cityId  
FROM register rfs 
INNER JOIN cities ct ON ct.id=rfs.cityId 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT empSignupId, COUNT(empSignupId) AS countGuest
  FROM guest_list gl 
  GROUP BY empSignupId
) gl  ON gl.empSignupId = rfs.empSignupId 
GROUP BY rfs.cityId;
```

**Output:**

```
COALESCE(SUM(countGuest), 0) + COUNT(rfs.id)    cityName    cityId
------------------------------------------------------------------
8                                               Bengaluru   1
2                                               Chennai     2
```

Using `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` guarantees that we also get cities without guests.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5fb3/14)

**Note:** If you also want to get cities without registrations then you need to place the `cities` table first and use a `LEFT JOIN` to `register`.

Comment: Works like a charm ! thanks .. I am still new to joins so I did not think of using Left join.

Comment: I count **4** emps **+ 4** guests for Bengaluru. So it should be **8**. You need to use `SUM(COALESCE(countGuest, 0))` or `COALESCE(SUM(countGuest), 0)`. Note that `countGuest` is not in the GROUP BY clause and neither is it functionally dependent on `cityId`.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel You are absolutely right, I will fix my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Use LEFT JOINS and add `count(distinct r.empSignupId) + count(distinct g.id)`:

```
select 
    c.id as cityId,
    c.cityName,
    count(distinct r.empSignupId) + count(distinct g.id) as people_count
from cities c
left join register r on r.cityId = c.id
left join guest_list g on g.empSignupId = r.empSignupId
group by c.id;
```

The result would be:

```
| cityId |      cityName | people_count |
|--------|---------------|--------------|
|      1 |     Bengaluru |            8 |
|      2 |       Chennai |            2 |
|      3 |        Sydney |            0 |
|      4 | New York City |            0 |
|      5 |      Shanghai |            0 |
|      6 |       Chicago |            0 |
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/OTBH14189

If you don't need the rows with `0`, change the first LEFT JOIN to an inner JOIN.